# de Sitter spacetime, spacetime without boundaries and holographic principle

Tags: spacetime, quantum-gravity, topology, holographic-principle, de-sitter-spacetime

One of the most intriguing aspects of black hole thermodynamics is that of holography or the holographic principle, namely, that the degrees of freedom of a putative theory of quantum gravity is somehow encoded into the boundary of the spacetime. This opens a puzzle for those spacetime, like the (quasi) de Sitter Universe in which we live in, since it has not an obvious boundary/holographic screen. My question is as follows: are there known examples of holographic theories formulated in spacetime with no boundary? Equivalently, is there any alternative formulation of the holographic principle with no need of a boundary?

Comment: Right before eq(3) in this article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0207245.pdf it is said that "early and late time infinities of de Sitter are natural holographic screen." Moreover, there are approaches of dS/CFT based on this "naturalness".